# Integration with animate.css when an item is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have just integrated this animate.css([http://daneden.me/animate/](http://daneden.me/animate)) into my website, but the animation happens when I load the page, therefore no animation can be seen if the element is down the bottom.
But I have found this http://www.crivosthemes.com/theme/porto/index-2.html, I'm pretty sure that they used the same animate.css but the animation happens when I scroll to the element.

I just want to ask, how did they do that? Is there any jquery thing or just css?

Please provide instructions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe they implement

```
window.onscroll = function(){
    //codes
    if(window.scrollTop == 100){
    //do something
    }
}
```

you can use javascript to trigger animation on that element....example

```
window.onscroll = function(){
     element.style.animation = "myanimation 2s infinite";
}
```